# what are the thing to required to install to run elgg 1.9.8 in centos7 in local environment

Tags: elgg

I need to run the elgg 1.9.8 site in centos7 present in local environment. What are the things to install in local environment to run the elgg 1.9.8 site. Can you please help me. Thank you advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache (with mod_rewrite enabled), PHP and MySQL are required to install an Elgg site.